# Accessing a variable of a Service

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android Activity called Main that calls a Service called MainService as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
if(MainService.getInstance() == null){
  Log.d(TAG, "Calling MainService");
  startService(intent);
}
```

MainService maintains a variable during its lifetime that I wish to access in Main later on. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use bind service to communicate between activity and service? I think this one will give you more flexibility to share data.

Comment: controversial question... but what is the advantage of binding to a service, instead of just accessing a public variable of a service directly? (as in, MainService.myVar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access variables inside service, but for that you have to bind to this service first. After that, use accessors for getting or setting variables or call any other method of the service.
See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Thanks. I made some modifications to the code, namely to bindService() in onCreate rather than onStart(), and to never unbind the service since I want the service to run indefinitely. It works, except I keep getting a "Activity has leaked ServiceConnection" error on my bindService() call. Also, every time I go back to my Activity, ServiceConnection seems to be called again. This should be 1 time, right? Does it have something to do with using bindService() rather than startService()?

Comment: OK, so I realized that services that are bound to activities are alive only when the activity is alive, i.e. it follows the activity lifecycle. So, I started the service from the activity using startService(), and then later on bind the service to the activity, and that works now.

Comment: controversial question... but what is the advantage of binding to a service, instead of just accessing a public variable of a service directly? (as in, myService.myVar)

Answer (score 5):

You can bind the service and can have the service instance forever. Below sample code will help you:-
Service Class

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    MyBinder binder=new MyBinder();
    MusicService services;
    static  Context context;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();

        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yaar);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MusicService getServiceSystem()
        {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MusicService services;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ServiceConnection connection=new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
              MusicService.MyBinder binderr=(MusicService.MyBinder)service;
                services=binderr.getServiceSystem();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

            }
        };

        Intent intent= new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

}
```

You can then use `service` anywhere you need in activity. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it seems like onServiceConnected() is never called? Hence, services is null and unusable.

Comment: @user1118764 make sure you declared in Manifest?